# finding and replacing all none translated words in .ctp files with their corresponding msgid from the .po file

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, gettext, po

I have a .po file like this:

```
msgid "Edit"
msgstr "تعديل"

msgid "Delete"
msgstr "حذف"

msgid "Are you sure you want to delete # %s?"
msgstr "هل تريد بالتأكيد حذف رقم # %s?"
```

and my .tpl files are like this:

```
<a href='#'><?php __('تعديل');?></a>
<a href='#'><?php __('حذف');?></a>
```

is there any cake bake command, or any php script, can help me finding and replacing all none translated words in .ctp files with their corresponding msgid from the .po file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automated script for that as part of cake that I am aware of, but you could do something with a custom PHP script and 'sed' I would guess.